# VBA Code - combining excel rows with negative numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get an excel sheet to go from this: (sorry my reputation isn't high enough to post pictures, so hosted them myself..)

[From this example](http://gearcentregroup.com/excel/VBA-1.JPG)

to

[this.](http://gearcentregroup.com/excel/VBA-2.JPG)

I have some VBA code I've found and modified:

*The girl who manages these excel sheets doesn't pre-sort by account number, like I did in the first screen shot above so that is also in the below code*

```
Sub MergeRows()
Dim iRow As Long, oCell As Object
Sheets(1).Activate
Columns("A:H").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
iRow = 1
Do While Len(Cells(iRow, 1)): DoEvents
If Cells(iRow, 1) = Cells(iRow + 1, 1) Then
For Each oCell In Rows(iRow).Cells
If oCell < Cells(iRow + 1, oCell.Column) Then
oCell = Cells(iRow + 1, oCell.Column)
End If
Next
Rows(iRow + 1).Delete
Else
iRow = iRow + 1
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

However, the

```
If oCell < Cells(iRow + 1, oCell.Column) Then
```

row seems to be causing the negative numbers to get deleted, since they are not greater then the blank cells above them. (right?) and I can't find a solution that A) doesn't delete the negative numbers and B) doesn't take an hour to run.

I have tried swaping that row with:

```
If Len(Trim(oCell)) = 0 Then
```

But when you get into the 100+ rows of accounts it takes a REALLY long time.

Is there some other way we can sort then combine the rows without losing the negatives or taking an hour to run?

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this.. but I'm new to the VBA code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does not require that the data be sorted, and it will correctly retain the negatives.  It should run fairly quickly:

```
Sub MergeRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngUnqAccts As Range
    Dim arrData() As Variant
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim rIndex As Long
    Dim cIndex As Long
    Dim ResultIndex As Long


    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    With ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        ws.Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells.Count)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count), True
        Set rngUnqAccts = Range(ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlUp))
        arrData = .Resize(, Columns("H").Column).Value
        ReDim arrResults(1 To rngUnqAccts.Cells.Count, 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
    End With

    For rIndex = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)
        ResultIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(arrData(rIndex, 1), rngUnqAccts, 0)
        If IsEmpty(arrResults(ResultIndex, 1)) Then
            arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = arrData(rIndex, 1)
            arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) = arrData(rIndex, 2)
        End If
        For cIndex = 3 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            If Len(arrData(rIndex, cIndex)) > 0 Then arrResults(ResultIndex, cIndex) = arrData(rIndex, cIndex)
        Next cIndex
    Next rIndex
    rngUnqAccts.EntireColumn.Clear

    ws.Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Resize(, UBound(arrData, 2)).ClearContents
    ws.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrResults, 1), UBound(arrResults, 2)).Value = arrResults


    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rngUnqAccts = Nothing
    Erase arrData
    Erase arrResults

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! So much better then what I came up with. :)